# RegExr in SQL password check Procedure

Tags: sql-server

I have an procedure to check password in SQL server, but its wrong, can someone explain and help me ?
If the password not contain 1 upper letter, 1 number and minium 8 charracter, this procedure will return an message.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE PaswordCompatibilityCheck
@Password nvarchar(200),
@ConfirmPassword nvarchar(200)
AS
BEGIN
    if @Password NOT LIKE '%(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}%'
    BEGIN
         SELECT 'The password must contain at least 1 capital letter and 1 number, minimum of 8 characters' as message, 'Error' as type
    RETURN -- We need return here for exit the procedure.
    END
END
----EXEC PaswordCompatibilityCheck 'PassWord101','PassWord101'
```

Comment: Why write a stored procedure to check password complexity? The database should never store or even see the cleartext password, so it makes little sense to use the database to check for complexity. Passwords are stored salted and hashed at least 1000 times, so the best place to check for complexity is in the web app or service, *before* hashing the password

Comment: As Panagiotis said: never let a password reach the database. This is such a bad security practice that it might even be held against you (e.g. gross neglect of due care - I am no lawyer) in case of a breach. Use the owasp guide (https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet.html) to implement a secure solution.

Comment: There is no Regex in SQL Server, so it's unclear what you are referring to anyway. `LIKE` is not Regex

Comment: You should [THROW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/throw-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) errors - don't return them as a resultset (in a specific language - yikes!) that must be interpreted by the calling code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server does not support native regex in this way.  However, its `LIKE` operator is enhanced and does support a bit of regex functionality.  You may try the following version:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE PaswordCompatibilityCheck
    @Password nvarchar(200),
    @ConfirmPassword nvarchar(200)
AS
    BEGIN
    IF NOT @Password LIKE '%[0-9]%' OR NOT @Password LIKE '%[A-Z]%' OR
           LEN(@Password) < 8
        BEGIN
            SELECT 'The password must contain at least 1 capital letter and 1 number, minimum of 8 characters' as message, 'Error' as type
    RETURN -- We need return here for exit the procedure.
    END
END

----EXEC PaswordCompatibilityCheck 'PassWord101','PassWord101'
```

Comment: Thanks bro but when i try with input 
EXEC PaswordCompatibilityCheck 'password101','password101'
it's still true :((

Comment: @JustStartlDev that's not what you asked - how to return different return values. You asked how to return a specific text. This stored procedure does exactly that. Besides, what's the purpose of this method? Passwords are never sent to the database in cleartext.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos ... unless bad unsecure design is being used.  Didn't think of that, but yes, cleartext passwords should never ever be sent to the DB, even in a stored proc.

Comment: Iknow that bro, but its my exercise homework, this procedure check password and return messeneger if the password not contain 1 upper letter, 1 number and minium 8  charracter bro

Comment: Try using @Password COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN LIKE '%[A-Z]%'

Comment: @AntonGrig my SQL server tell me Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'COLLATE'.

Comment: thank u, i got it, thanks all brother